# How access to list in angular object (getting by Java Rest)

Tags: java, angularjs, jhipster

I use Jhipster for generate my code.

I have a class Calendar with list of Event.
I want to access to events list in my angular controller / view.
I can access to Object Calendar with query Java Rest.
But calendar.events is undifined, can't access directly to list.

How declare events list in controller ?

**Java Parts :** 
Calendar.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "calendar", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();
```

Event.java

```
@ManyToOne
private Calendar calendar;
```

CalendarResource.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calendars/{id}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public ResponseEntity<Calendar> getCalendar(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Calendar : {}", id);
    Calendar calendar = calendarRepository.findOne(id);
    return Optional.ofNullable(calendar)
        .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(
            result,
            HttpStatus.OK))
        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/calendars",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public ResponseEntity<List<Calendar>> getAllCalendars(Pageable pageable)
    throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Calendars");
    Page<Calendar> page = calendarRepository.findAll(pageable); 
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/calendars");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Angular Parts**
calendar.service.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('mandefaApp')
    .factory('Calendar', Calendar);

Calendar.$inject = ['$resource'];

function Calendar ($resource) {
    var resourceUrl =  'api/calendars/:id';

    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                }
                return data;
            }
        },
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}
```

})();

calendar.controller.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('mandefaApp')
    .controller('CalendarController', CalendarController);

CalendarController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Calendar', 'CalendarSearch', 'ParseLinks', 'AlertService', 'pagingParams', 'paginationConstants'];

function CalendarController ($scope, $state, Calendar, CalendarSearch, ParseLinks, AlertService, pagingParams, paginationConstants) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.loadPage = loadPage;
    vm.predicate = pagingParams.predicate;
    vm.reverse = pagingParams.ascending;
    vm.transition = transition;
    vm.itemsPerPage = paginationConstants.itemsPerPage;
    vm.clear = clear;
    vm.search = search;
    vm.loadAll = loadAll;
    vm.searchQuery = pagingParams.search;
    vm.currentSearch = pagingParams.search;

    loadAll();

    function loadAll () {
        if (pagingParams.search) {
            CalendarSearch.query({
                query: pagingParams.search,
                page: pagingParams.page - 1,
                size: vm.itemsPerPage,
                sort: sort()
            }, onSuccess, onError);
        } else {
            Calendar.query({
                page: pagingParams.page - 1,
                size: vm.itemsPerPage,
                sort: sort()
            }, onSuccess, onError);
        }
        function sort() {
            var result = [vm.predicate + ',' + (vm.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
            if (vm.predicate !== 'id') {
                result.push('id');
            }
            return result;
        }
        function onSuccess(data, headers) {
            vm.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
            vm.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
            vm.queryCount = vm.totalItems;
            vm.calendars = data;
            vm.page = pagingParams.page;
        }
        function onError(error) {
            AlertService.error(error.data.message);
        }
    }

    function loadPage (page) {
        vm.page = page;
        vm.transition();
    }

    function transition () {
        $state.transitionTo($state.$current, {
            page: vm.page,
            sort: vm.predicate + ',' + (vm.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc'),
            search: vm.currentSearch
        });
    }

    function search (searchQuery) {
        if (!searchQuery){
            return vm.clear();
        }
        vm.links = null;
        vm.page = 1;
        vm.predicate = '_score';
        vm.reverse = false;
        vm.currentSearch = searchQuery;
        vm.transition();
    }

    function clear () {
        vm.links = null;
        vm.page = 1;
        vm.predicate = 'id';
        vm.reverse = true;
        vm.currentSearch = null;
        vm.transition();
    }
}
```

})();

**Html Code :**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="jh-table table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr jh-sort="vm.predicate" ascending="vm.reverse" callback="vm.transition()">
                <th jh-sort-by="id"><span translate="global.field.id">ID</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
                <th jh-sort-by="title"><span translate="mandefaApp.calendar.title">Title</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
                <th jh-sort-by="title">Event Size <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="calendar in vm.calendars track by calendar.id">
                <td><a ui-sref="calendar-detail({id:calendar.id})">{{calendar.id}}</a></td>
                <td>{{calendar.title}}</td>
                <td>{{calendar.events.lenght}}</td> <!-- How can access to events in calendar object ? -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed you have this `@jsonignore` annotation on your POJO?

> The Jackson annotation @JsonIgnore is used to tell Jackson to ignore a
>   certain property (field) of a Java object. The property is ignored
>   both when reading JSON into Java objects, and when writing Java
>   objects into JSON.

Try removing it.

Source: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok resolved !

Its because i have a infinite while : In my Data i get Events, all event object contain Calendar Object => contain event ... and again and again...

I add @JsonIgnore to Event.java on Calendar object.

Fixed !